# Error creating a new Visual Studio c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

As I try to create a new c++ project in Visual Studio I have the error

> the project file could not be loaded. root element is missing

the error is at the Cpp.Win32.user.props(0,0)

do somebody know how to fix the error?

Comment: Did you try deleting the following file: 
"C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props"
And restarting Visual Studio? It seems to be a common error.

Comment: It works. thank you

Comment: Okay, please accept my answer, then we can close the question. :)
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try deleting the following file: "C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Micr‌​osoft.Cpp.Win32.user‌​.props" And restarting Visual Studio? It seems to be a common error.